# How can I keep two flexbox elements the same size within differently sized containers?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

This is going to be relatively hard to explain without a visual demonstration, so see the jsfiddle at the bottom.

The setup is two column-direction flexbox containers that have a relative height (i.e. a percentage of their parent). Both containers have a fixed header and a footer. One container is always twice the height of the other. The larger container has two children as its 'content'. The smaller container has one child 'content' element.

I would like the first content element of the larger container to always be the same height as the single content element in the smaller container, regardless of the sizes of the containers. For any given size, I can specify a flex-grow that matches the elements, but it will not work for every size.

Is this possible using flexbox?

```
<div id="card1" class="card">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="content2"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>

<div id="card2" class="card">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>


html, body {height: 100%;}

body {
  display: flex;
}

#card1 {
  height: 80%;
  background-color: green;
}

#card2 {
  height: 40%;
  background-color: green;
}

.card {
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 4px;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 24px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightseagreen;
  flex: 1;
}

.content2 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: limegreen;
  flex: 1;
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 24px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d1pvg6ty/2/)

This question should be the same if the flex direction was instead row and I was talking about width and not height.

Comment: just want to be clear: If card1 is always twice the height of card2 and content blocks always have the same height. The way your code looks, does that mean that content2 block can be slightly more height than content block?

Comment: Yes, I would expect the content2 block to fill the remaining space - I forgot to mention that.

Comment: is the content height responsive or fixed? Like if the content in card2 or 1 changes, does the other one always need to match the height of the other one?

Comment: Well the content height is responsive by default since it is being positioned using flexbox inside a responsive container...but you can assume that the ratio will always be the same I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly how you want it but just based as closely as possible to what you have. First, we would need to take away the extra height from the card1 content container to (padding of the card plus the footer). By doing so, you'll need to "give back" the starting point by set `margin-top: -44px` for `content2`. I also add `overflow: hidden` to the content container.

```css
html, body {height: 100%;}

body {
  display: flex;
}

#card1 {
  height: 80%;
  background-color: green;
}

#card2 {
  height: 40%;
  background-color: green;
}

.card {
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 24px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.content > p{
  margin-top: 0
}
.content2 {
  padding-top: 44px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: tomato;
  flex: 1;
}
.content2 > p{
  margin-top: -44px;
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 24px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="card1" class="card">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>
      ed ut perspiciatis ed ut perspiciatis one voluptatem sequi nesciunt Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit ametvelit ed ut perspiciatis one voluptatem sequi nesciunt Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit ametvelit
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="content2">
    <p>Neque porro quisquam est</p>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>

<div id="card2" class="card">
  <div class="header">Header 2</div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>
      ed ut perspiciatis ed ut perspiciatis one voluptatem sequi nesciunt Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit ametvelit ed ut perspiciatis rspiciatis ed ut perspiciatis one voluptatem sequi nesciunt Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit ametvelit ed ut perspiciatis
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">Footer 2</div>
</div>
```